# Is Vim really that good?

Tags: vim

I had to see what all the fuss was about Vim so tried it out for a little while; built a whole site in it. In the end I decided I was less productive.

So my question is: is Vim really that good or is it just one of those ultra-nerdy things people want to use so they can say: "I use Vim". Vim seems a little cumbersome to me. I know it's supposed to be lean but I think the years development and the mass of contributes has left it untidy. Am I wrong? Should I stick it out with Vim? What are the advantages of Vim?

Comment: pick one and learn to use it very well.

Comment: It's impossible to objectively answer this question, but sometimes, a little subjective discourse is useful. I for one, would like to see where an adult discussion on this topic would lead.

Answer (score 5):

[How I learn to stop worrying and love VIM](http://www.stimuli.com.br/trane/2009/sep/19/how-i-learn-stop-worrying-and-love-vim/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I'm in the "I-just-want-an-editor-stage"